# Javascript or jQuery Autoresize script

Tags: javascript, jquery, autoresize

So in Firefox versions lower than 7 this script was working (it is auroresizing the browser window to maximum of visitors monitor). Now in FF 7 + it seems that it is not working. If you can find out why it is not working, or if you can give me similar one i will be fery very thankful! Here is my code:

```
<script language="JavaScript1.2">

top.window.moveTo(0,0);
if (document.all) {
    top.window.resizeTo(screen.availWidth,screen.availHeight);
}
else if (document.layers||document.getElementById) {
    if (top.window.outerHeight < screen.availHeight || top.window.outerWidth < screen.availWidth){
        top.window.outerHeight = screen.availHeight;
        top.window.outerWidth = screen.availWidth;
    }
}

</script>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"? Are you getting an error?

Comment: @ZachRattner nah, its simply doing nothing...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [fine manual](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.outerHeight):

> The window.outerHeight property is read-only.

The same holds for `window.outerWidth`. There is [`resizeTo`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.resizeTo) and [`resizeBy`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.resizeBy) but the browser won't necessarily pay attention to your humble request.

The size of the browser window is the user's choice and resizing their window is a bit rude so many browsers won't let you do it.